# The argument type 'CollectionReference<Object?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Query<Map<String, dynamic>>'. (Documentation)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

[image]I'm writing an app to show nearby ATMs. I want to pass the collection refernce and i get this error.

```
Stream nearbyATM() async* {
    GeoFirePoint point = geo.point(latitude: _position!.latitude, longitude: _position!.longitude);
    final CollectionReference atms = _firestore.collection("atms");
    double radius = 100;
    String field = "location";
    Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream = geo
                            .collection(collectionRef: atms)
                            .within(center: point, radius: radius, field: field);
  }
```

[image: In CollectionReference atms error]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the `.within()` method with the [**GeoFlutterFire**](https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire#query-geo-data) package, you need to pass a Query object as an argument to the **GeoFireCollectionRef.collection()** method.

You can directly use `var query =  _firestore.collection("atms").where(field, isLessThanOrEqualTo: point.distance, isGreaterThan: point.distance - radius);` to make the inference do it’s thing but If we can also define the Types implicitly as follows:

```js
Stream nearbyATM() async* {
  GeoFirePoint point = geo.point(latitude: _position!.latitude, longitude: _position!.longitude);
  double radius = 100;
  String field = "location";
// Let the Auto inference do it’s thing
  Query<Map<String, dynamic>> query =  _firestore.collection("atms").where(field, isLessThanOrEqualTo: point.distance, isGreaterThan: point.distance - radius);
// You can also 
  Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream = geo.collection(collectionRef: query).within(center: point, radius: radius, field: field);
}
```

We can pass Firebase Query to the [collectionRef](https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire#scale-to-massive-collections) of `geo.collection` not just CollectionRef of firestore only.

Reference : [**geoflutterfire**](https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire).